# Missing Operating System & Blinking Curson

Tags: boot

So my laptop hard drive decided to die a few days ago. I went out and bought a new one, loaded Ubuntu onto it using the USB installer and formatted it as FAT32. However upon putting this into the laptop I just get `Missing Operating System` and when trying to boot it from USB I just get a blinking cursor. I've tried formatting lots of times and downloaded different Ubuntu versions but nothing is working. Yet when I plug the drive in another computer it loads the drive up fine and I can see all the files in explorer etc...

Comment: Why would you install Ubuntu on fat32, which doesn't support Unix file permissions? Try ext4 instead.

Comment: Because that's what it says to format that drive as....

Comment: You are supposed to format the USB as fat32, not your PC's hard drive.  Use ext4 for the PC's hard drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure it actually boots from the USB drive? It seems to me that is trying to boot from the hard drive and as it says there's no Operating System on it (yet). You may need to change the boot sequence (temporarily). The second computer apparently does boot the USB drive.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick answer, I've tried changing the boot sequence in the BIOS from Hard Drive to USB etc...

Comment: What happened after this change?

Comment: Still does the same thing. Just says missing operating system. or when changing to USB it just has a blinking cursor.

Comment: I'm confused now. Either you did edit the question or I did read it wrong. What exactly are you booting from is it a USB hard drive meaning it is an external drive or is it a USB pendrive? If it is a pendrive then using fat32 is possible. If it is a USB hard drive I recommend you to format it as ext4. If it is an external hard drive I'm pretty sure it isn't used to boot from if there's still an internal hard drive in the system, unless you did change the bootorder.